# CurlException Issue with Shopify

Tags: php, shopify

I am using `phpish\shopify`. It was working smoothly for 2 years and all of sudden now its throwing -

> phpish\shopify\CurlException: [28] connect() timed out

It works fine on `localhost` & on testing server but on LIVE its having this problem.I have tried setting `CURLOPT_SSLVERSION` =>`3` in curl options yet no luch so far.please if anyone has encountered similar issue please help

Comment: what's the output of `ping your_shopify_site.com`?

Comment: Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:                                   Minimum = 322ms, Maximum = 326ms, Average = 324ms

Answer (score 0):

It may be the issue with your server configuration.

You need to check php.ini
Have you did any changes on live server?